# logback.xml : overriding root level for one class only

Tags: java, xml, logback

Given the following root in logback.xml:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

defining the following logging rule:

```
<logger name="com.myproject.mypackage.MyClass" level="DEBUG">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

The log level in myclass won't be DEBUG, because the root level is info. But I want to see debug logs in this particular class ONLY. Is that achieveable without changing the root level (which would cause the app to vomit debug logs from all over the place)?

EDIT: I tried this as well:

```
<logger name="com.myproject" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="com.myproject.mypackage.MyClass" level="DEBUG">

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

So the idea was to set the root to debug so everything is DEBUG, but set everything under 'com.myproject' to info so the log level really is INFO, but set MyClass to DEBUG. It didn't work :(

Comment: You config seems fine. Don't you see nothing in the stdout ? You should check the way you are logging.

Comment: you mean this setup should result in MyClass logging DEBUGs?

Comment: Yes. You should maybe show how you log.

Comment: Same issue. No solution yet?

Comment: Looking for the same solution... Some news?

Comment: Is there another `logback.xml` in your storage? I have encounterd the same problem, and the cause was that I have edited the file not in the classpath (I have imported the files in another project by using `svn:externals`, and it had confused me).

Answer (score 11):

"Root" level does not restrict levels of other loggers, it merely sets the default. So `<root level="INFO">` and `<logger name="some.name" level="DEBUG">` are perfectly suitable together, and you don't need to relax the "root" level. So both examples should log on debug level for logger named `com.myproject.mypackage.MyClass`. So if your configuration logs something and does not log from `com.myproject.mypackage.MyClass`, the problem should be in another place.

Also, if you want some logger to log into its own appender only, as in the first example, you should use `additivity="false"` attribute on `logger`, otherwise it will log to both root appenders and logger-specific appenders.

For example:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("some.logger").info("info msg");
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("another.logger").info("info msg");
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("another.logger").error("error msg");
    }
}
```

logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>STDOUT: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>STDOUT2: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="some.logger" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT2" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Result:

```
STDOUT2: 16:58:58.973 [main] INFO  some.logger - info msg
STDOUT: 16:58:58.979 [main] ERROR another.logger - error msg
```

Comment: Does anyone know where "in another place" could be?

Comment: @sjngm Most often there is a conflicting logback config somewhere in the classpath. See order of search in the first section of http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html Use `-Dlogback.debug=true` to enable debugging of the logback setup.